# Calculate optimal surroundings for given reaction mechanism to lower activation energy?

Tags: reaction-mechanism, computational-chemistry, catalysis, enzymes

Let's take a reaction that's fairly well understood, which in this case means that the reaction mechanism is known, maybe something like this from [here](http://www.chemtube3d.com/Oppolzer.html):

[image]

If we know the reaction mechanism, we also know or can infer with some reasonable degree of accuracy the paths of all the atoms between reaction start and finish.

Is there a way to calculate surroundings, perhaps just electron densities to begin with, in which the activation energy is minimal for this reaction? (Yes, I realize that another way to put this is "can we begin designing a catalyst for this reaction mechanism?")

Comment: The only generally applicable way is brute force.  Example: https://peerj.com/articles/111/